# Remove string from multiple rows SQL

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a table that has "HQ created..." in 100+ rows. Instead of manually updating those rows I want to trim that part off.

I tried:

`UPDATE Table SET Desc = LTRIM('HQ created')  WHERE Desc LIKE '%HQ created%'`

and that changed all 100+ rows to "HQ created" instead of cutting that part off.

(*`I also tried SET HADEDesc = RTRIM('HQ created')`*)

A replace will not work as outside of the "HQ created..." the names are different for example "*HQ created Date*" and "*HQ created Time*".

Comment: Your question doesn't make clear why `REPLACE(HADEDesc, 'HQ created ', '')` wouldn't work.

Comment: @JeroenMostert It is possible i was using it incorrectly, as the below replace worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update table
set desc = replace(Desc, 'HQ created' , '')
 WHERE Desc LIKE '%HQ created%'
```